# SQL How to count all remains for each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I have the following SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCardDepartRemains] 
(
    @CardId INT,
    @DepartId INT,
    @Date DATETIME = NULL,
    @DocumentId INT = NULL
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Res INT

    SELECT
        @Res = ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Operations.[Output] = 0 AND Operations.RecipientId = @DepartId THEN 1 ELSE -1 END), 0)
    FROM dbo.Operations
    WHERE  Operations.CardId = @CardId
        AND (Operations.[Output] = 0 AND Operations.RecipientId = @DepartId OR Operations.Input = 0 AND Operations.SenderId = @DepartId)
        AND (@Date IS NULL OR Operations.[Date] <= @Date)

    RETURN @Res
END
GO
```

It counts remains for certain product on certain department on certain date.

If it is less then zero it means something's wrong with database

Now I need to find all remains for each card, for each department for all dates in database where result is wrong.

Theoretically speaking we can fing this by calling this procedure in a query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Operations.[Date] as [Date],
        Departments.Id as Depart,
        Cards.Id as [Card],
        [dbo].[GetCardDepartRemains] (Cards.Id, Departments.Id,Operations.[Date],NULL) as Res

FROM [jewellery].[dbo].[Cards] 
    CROSS JOIN [jewellery].[dbo].[Departments] 
    CROSS JOIN [jewellery].[dbo].[Operations]
WHERE [dbo].[GetCardDepartRemains] (Cards.Id, Departments.Id,Operations.[Date],NULL) = -1
```

But this query executes more than 2 minutes, so we need to write a new query.

My query can find all remains for each card on each department on certain date (ex. '2016-10-04')

```
SELECT 
    [Card],
    Depart,
    Res
FROM          
    (SELECT
        Cards.Id as [Card],
        Departments.Id as Depart,
        ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN Operations.[Output] = 0 AND Operations.RecipientId = Departments.Id THEN 1 ELSE -1 END), 0) as Res
    FROM Operations
    CROSS JOIN Cards
    CROSS JOIN Departments
    WHERE  Operations.CardId = Cards.Id
    AND (Operations.[Output] = 0 AND Operations.RecipientId = Departments.Id OR Operations.Input = 0 AND Operations.SenderId = Departments.Id)
    AND (Operations.[Date] <= '2016-10-04') 

    GROUP BY Cards.Id, Departments.Id
    ) as X
WHERE Res = -1
```

Can you help to re-write this query to find remains for all dates?

Comment: which version of sql server are you on?

Comment: It might be enough to just change your function to be an inline function. The problem with using a scalar function is that it will execute it twice for each of the rows you have in your query -- and SQL server is not good in row-by-row iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server is 2008 or above:

To find all dates, just comment out the date filter like this:

```
-- AND (Operations.[Date] <= '2016-10-04')
```

If you need to filter on a date range:

```
AND (Operations.[Date] between between getDate()-30 and getDate()
```

Changing -30 to however many days in the past. So a year ago would be -364.